# How to fill NA values in a sequenced(ordered) numeric column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column like this with NaN values

**

```
Num

10,
11,
NaN,
13
14,
NaN,
16
17
18
19
```

**

I need to fill the NA values in the existing order of values like this
,
**

```
Num
10,
11,
12,
13
14,
15,
16
17
18
19
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as using linear [`interpolation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

```
df['Num'].interpolate()
```

---

```
Num
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Just notice that some lines appear to have a comma (i.e. `,` char) along with the numbers, which would cause your column to be of `object` dtype. You might wanna enforce that you work with numeric dtypes for this, in which case you'd have to do something like the following before using interpolation:

```
df['Num'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['Num'].str.strip(','), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, Interpolate worked just fine. No, my bad, there are no ","'